# Is Zend Gdata maintained?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-gdata

Is it worth using Zend Framework for Google calendar or in other words Gdata ? I heard that it is not maintained anymore. Is it true?
With regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the github repository it isn't maintained anymore:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData

> This component is unmaintained. If you require API access to the Google api, please consider using https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/